# neo4j performance issue when filtering nodes

Tags: neo4j

What is the most efficient way to match all path that contains node with label a, b or c but which can contains other type of nodes.
It works for smaller graph but got performance issue on larger.

For example :

- a -> b -> c must be matched
- a -> b -> d -> c must be matched
- a -> b -> d no match
- a -> b no match

Any idea ?
I did it with with

```
MATCH (a)
WHERE exists((a)-->(b)) and exists((a)-->(c))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with this:

```
MATCH (a)-[*]->(b)-[*]->(c)
```

This allows any number of nodes between `a` and `b` and between `b` and `c`. Depending on the number of nodes you have, this might not be very performant. In that case, I would work with indices (which are cheap in Neo4j) to speed things up, and perhaps even script your Cypher query using Python and dynamic string replacement.